# Ambiguous Use of Subscript in Swift?

Tags: ios, swift

i am having data at indexpath at section.
when i try to retrive data it is working on simulator.
but when i test on device it gives error
"Ambiguous Use of Subscript in Swift"

here is my code

```
let newProductDic = arr[indexPath.section][indexPath.row]
```

please help me find out the issue what is correct syntax

Comment: how is the arr defined?

Comment: This error is probably because you did not cast `arr[indexPath.section]` to the correct type.

Comment: than what is correct sytnax

Comment: The type of `arr` is most likely `[AnyObject]` or undefined. So the compiler doesn't know – we don't either –  that it's supposed to contain another array.

Comment: than how should i define array

Comment: Declare it with the actual type!

Comment: i define as " var arr   : NSMutableArray = [ ] '

Comment: Do not inherit from NSMutableArray at all. Use var (for mutating) and Array type.

Comment: `NSMutableArray` is bad because it's type undefined. Declare it as Swift nested `Array`, at least `[[AnyObject]]` but better as the actual type of the row object.

Comment: according to your code, your arr must contain another array
OR 
you have to typecast arr[indexPath.section] to Array.

Comment: @HirenPanchal syntax?

Comment: @KrutarthPatel
let newObject = arr[indexPath.section] as? [AnyObject]
and then use your code as
let newProductDic = newObject[indexPath.row]

Comment: @KrutarthPatel What type is the object for the `row` (the inner array) ?

Comment: @vadian  let indexPath = NSIndexPath(forRow: indexPath.row, inSection: indexPath.section)

Comment: No, not the index path, what type are the objects in your `NSMutableArray`? We are as confused as the compiler.

Comment: @vadian haha. i declare array like     var arr          : NSMutableArray = [ ]

Comment: its not your falut.its mine.thanks

Comment: @HirenPanchal please add your comment as answer.so i can accept.your comment works for me

Comment: @KrutarthPatel Have added answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
let newObject = arr[indexPath.section] as? [AnyObject]
```

and then use your code as

```
let newProductDic = newObject[indexPath.row]
```